# Is it good way to use /tmp in application for storing temporary files?

Tags: tmp

In my application, we store temporary images generated from PDF in /tmp/pdf_images folder. Is it a standard practice? Or It's not recommended to use of /tmp from application code?

Comment: I think you should precise the targeted OS in tag. I assumed linux or MacOS but the answer could have to be completed for a wider or different target.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're on linux or MacOS, this directory is just there for this.

Be sure to have them automatically deleted at closing of your application.

And note that they may be purged by the OS or the user (directly or not) at any moment when your application isn't running. And generally, it's totally cleaned at reboot (and every 3 days on MacOS).